# Lab test for Pregnancy, Not Clearly listed?

Tags: medications, blood, blood-tests, obstetrics, prescription

Can anyone list the Laboratory Test that are prescribed in the picture?(It's for a pregnancy in week 28+1).

[image]

Comment: Hi! Here at Health SE, we don't answer personal health questions as it's better to contact your healthcare provider for these. I tried to make your question less personal by edits, which if you don't like can be reedited or undone. You should contact whoever ordered these for clarification. Your situation is delicate and needs a skilled physician's care. Good luck and thanks!

Comment: @Pobrecita You added "man" to the title. What does "man test" mean?

Comment: @CareyGregory Lol, I'm on my phone it's autocorrect, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Pobrecita Thanks, I know it. but for upgrade my knowledge I ask it here. thanks

Comment: @Pobrecita It certainly was confusing in a question about pregnancy tests. ;-)